Original search for an article about independent sets.
The following article were cited many times, but there doesn't seem to be an electronic version available for reading. I'm not sure where to find it.

Y. Caro, Y. Roditty, On the vertex-independence number and star decomposition of graphs, Ars Combin. 20:167-180, 1985

